# SQL Pull COLUMNS meeting specific criteria not ROWS

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Table1  
Buyer   Product
John    Car
Sammy   Car
Jacob   Car
Sara    Car
Jesus   Car
Sean    Car
John    House
Sammy   House
Jacob   House
John    Boat
Sammy   Boat
```

My Query:

```
Select *
From (
    Select Distinct Buyer
    Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY Buyer ORDER BY Product) AS Uniqueness
    From Table1
    Where product <> 'Boat'
) As Z
```

Where Uniqueness =1

Results are:

```
Buyer
John
Sammy
Jacob
Sara
Jesus
Sean
```

Results desired:

```
Buyer
Jacob
Sara
Jesus
Sean
```

I'm only looking for the PEOPLE who don't have a boat not the ROWS that don't have a boat. The reason i have the partition is because in my actual query it is needed so i wanted to include it here so any solution also takes it into consideration THANK YOU!

Comment: You'll likely need a proper related table design. Something like: `Table: Buyers (id name), Table: Boats (id, name), PivotTable: buyer_boats (buyer_id, boat_id)`. You can then perform your desired query with ease.

Comment: I edited my initial question to better reflect my ACTUAL query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses aggregation:

```
select buyer
from t
group by buyer
having sum(case when product = 'Boat' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;  -- no boats
```

However, if you have a separate table of buyers, then `not exists` is probably more appropriate:

```
select b.*
from buyers b
where not exists (select 1 from t where t.buyer = b.buyer and t.product = 'Boat');
```

This will return buyers who have made no purchases as well.  But by avoiding the outer aggregation (or distinct) it is likely to be faster with the right indexes.

Comment: What if i wanted the opposite to be true? As in now i want to return ONLY buyers who DID purchase a boat vs didint?

Comment: @Mo-L . . . Then you would have a different question.  A `where` clause would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Its better if you have an ID field instead of just buyer name.  I will show a query that depends on Buyer being unique

```
Select Buyer
From Table1 T1
Left Join Table1 T2 On T1.Buyer = T2.Buyer And T2.product = 'Boat'
Where T2.Buyer Is Null
```